# Is it safe to ignore .appx files in Git repository of a UWP app?

Tags: git, github, uwp, appx

I used the VisualStudio .gitignore file found [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) when I created the repository for my UWP app.

Now when the repository files are added for the first time into the master branch, the .appx files are added too.

[GitHub Desktop screenshot: .appx files are added to the repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7M6i.jpg)

Wondered if they are necessary and if I can safely add .appx to the .gitignore file.

Comment: Delete the appx files, run the app. If it doesn't work the answer is no, if it does the answer is yes.

Comment: It works after I deleted the appx files. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the .appx files in the repo, you can add the whole AppPackages folder to .gitignore.

Comment: The AppPackages folder was already in the .gitignore, but not the .appx extension. And .appx files created in the project root directory were not excluded. I did a pull request on GitHub. Thank you for the answer.